# Building a reverse proxy w/ Express

Tags: express, reverse-proxy

I'm working on a project where I'm currently trying to set up a reverse proxy via express which will serve up several static components compiled by webpack. A quick scheme of what I'm trying to do.

```
Client -> Reverse Proxy Server -> Component Server (10 total individual servers)
```

Any request from the client will have to go through the reverse proxy server and then that request should get forwarded to the correct component server. How can I go about achieving this? I don't see any documentation in expressjs that mentions how to do this. Theres a package here https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware that will let me do exactly what I want but I've been forbidden from using it. Any direction/help towards documentation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd follow up on this - the listed http-proxy-middleware seems to have a lot of bloating. I got it to work to forward my requests but measuring the performance vs. an API call via axios was much faster and more performant in terms of handling a higher number of requests from users.